# A single word or phrase when someone pretends to be so close to you

Tags: single-word-requests, phrase-requests

I know that I came from a country where inventing words or phrase for something is common. I always hear this phrase when they say it:

> you're so feeling close

to denote that someone pretends to be your *close* friend or vice versa. I'm not just that confident that the usage of this phrase is valid. I believe that we're the only one who used this.

A singled word or phrase will do.

Comment: There are many common words and phrases used, depending upon the intentions of the pretender.  Including *leech* or *false friend*.  Could you narrow down your requirements a little.

Comment: Google Books claims 681 written instances of [**pseudo-intimate**](https://www.google.com/search?tbm=bks&q=%22pseudo-intimate%22), but we need more context to know if that's an appropriate term for OP's requirements.

Comment: The person is *overly familiar."  The person is showing *false intimacy*.

Answer (score 3):

They are apparently trying to ***cosy up*** to you.

M-W:

> **[cozy up](http://www.merriam-webster.com/dictionary/cozy%20up)**
>   *intransitive verb*
>   :  to attain or try to attain familiarity, friendship, or intimacy :  ingratiate oneself : *cozying up to the
>   boss*

Comment: Cosying up does not carry a connotation of pretence - as mentioned in the question.

Comment: @Chenmunka: Not so - it often *does*. Note ***try to attain*** and ***ingratiate*** in the definition, and the contextual implications of the specific example *cozying up to the boss* (usually for career advancement, *not* because you like him! :)

Comment: @FumbleFingers: I don't see that ingratiation is the same as pretence.  More a sycophantic attempt to become a friend - a true friend.  Especially if more normal opening encounters are spurned.

Comment: @Chenmunka: Well, you can certainly "cosy up" to a family member, close friend, or (prospective?) sexual partner on the sofa, and hopefully there's no pretence there. But in the common-as-muck figurative usage where it's effectively a more euphemistic alternative to, say, ***brownnose***, I think the implied lack of sincerity is practically a given.

Answer (score 0):

I wonder if such a "friend" might be classified as a *fair weather friend?* I suggest that any friendship extended by a fair-weather friend is merely superficial and ceases to be even that when any sincere friendship is tested and found to be wanting in times of trouble.

**fair-weather friend:** (BrE) Someone who is a good friend when it is easy to be one and who stops being one when you are having problems (Cambridge Dictionary).

Comment: "My father taught me many things...He taught me -- keep your friends close but your enemies closer."   Michael Corleone in The Godfather Part ll.