# I need a word for this situation/person

Tags: single-word-requests

I have a friend who acts horribly mean to people but whenever he needs something from the person he has been mean to, it is like he becomes another person. He acts extremely nice.However, even if he does get the thing he wants he instantly goes back to being mean. I have been trying to find a word that describes this person but I can't seem to find it. Any ideas?

Comment: Answered at [A single word or phrase when someone pretends to be so close to you](https://english.stackexchange.com/questions/352688/a-single-word-or-phrase-when-someone-pretends-to-be-so-close-to-you)

Comment: How about a **user**?

Comment: I don't know a word for this person, but the word for a person who lets him behave this way is "enabler."

Answer (score 0):

**two-faced**

**1. Having two faces or surfaces.
2. Hypocritical or double-dealing; deceitful.

http://www.thefreedictionary.com/two-faced

Comment: In my experience ***two-faced*** is most often used where a person acts in a friendly and reasonably way with one person, and perhaps accepts favours from them, whilst complaining about them behind their back.

Answer (score 0):

When he acts nice just to get what he wants out of the person, you could say he is being **disingenuous**, i.e. not acting like his true self.